# How to create custom button class and add default features

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I'm trying to create a custom button class but I can't set the default text size and background.

**ButtonGray.kt**

```
class ButtonGray(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton(context, attrs) {

    init {
        textSize = 30.0F
        background = R.drawable.bg_btn_gray
    }
}
```

[ButtonGray.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwOsV.png)

[text size cannot be assigned by default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyIs5.png)

EDIT:

I try this code:

```
 background = context?.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_btn_gray)
```

Does not give an error. But it didn't work by default.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HWX6.png)

Comment: Why not do this with styles? The class should define the behavior. The sytle should define the appearance.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: It’s all in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
   
class ButtonGray : AppCompatButton {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?
    ) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {

        width= resources.getDimension(R.dimen.your_dimen).toInt()
        height= resources.getDimension(R.dimen.your_dimen).toInt()

        setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.yourColor))

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please consider writing a sentence or two describing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have a created a custom button in Kotlin.

```html
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
import com.urfeed.R


class PrimaryButton : AppCompatButton {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context){
        init()
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?
    ) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        init()
    }


    private fun init() {
        this.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient)
        this.textSize = 10f
        this.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white))
    }

    fun turnIntoPrimary(text: String){
        this.text = text
        this.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.primary_bkg_drawable)
        postInvalidate()
    }

     fun turnIntoSecondary(text: String){
        this.text = text
        this.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.secondary_bkg_drawable)
        postInvalidate()
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

button.turnIntoPrimary("Primary")

button.turnIntoSecondary("Secondary")

Answer (score 0):

Use this class and customize in init section

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton

class ButtonGray(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) :        AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0) {
    init()
}
constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0) {
    init()
}

init {
    setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg_btn_gray)
    textSize = 30.0F
    text = "Hello"
}}
```

I have Java Way of implementation. which is working
You have to read attributes for background, size etc. Put some default value in case not set and set these to button like below code

Read Attributes

```
TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.IGButton,0,0);
    try {
        setType(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.IGButton_buttonType,0));
        setiConPos(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.IGButton_iconPos,0));
        borderWidth = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.IGButton_borderWidth, Constants.BUTTON_BORDER_WIDTH);
        radius = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.IGButton_borderRadius, Constants.BUTTON_BORDER_RADIUS);
        fontSize = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.IGButton_fontSizeSP, Constants.BUTTON_TEXT_FONT_SIZE);
        int drawableId = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.IGButton_smallIcon, 0);
        if(drawableId > 0) {
            icon = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId, context.getTheme());
        }
    }
    finally {
        attributes.recycle();
    }
```

Set it like

```
this.setTextColor(textColor);
this.setAllCaps(false);
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
    ((Button)this).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
```

Set Custom Background

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setColor(backgroundColor);
    drawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
    drawable.setStroke(borderWidth, borderColor);
    this.setBackground(drawable);
    StateListAnimator animator =  AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(context,
            R.animator.button_animation_set);
    ((Button)this).setStateListAnimator(animator);
```

Comment: I updated answer. Some code in java you may have to write in kotlin.